# How do I get an inserted document ID in Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to return the document id after inserting a new document in Google Cloud Firebase?

Here is a sample of my save method so far:

```
save(entity:any){
    entity = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entity)); 

    if(entity.id){
        return db.collection(this.collectionName).doc(entity.id).update(entity);
    }else{
        // How to return the newly created document id from here?
        return db.collection(this.collectionName).doc().set(entity);
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is a highlighted example of the value document Id that I am referring to

[image]

Comment: Do you mean returning the string ID from the function `save` that you've written here?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I am referring to the unique string id assigned to the document automatically

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added a specific screenshot of the data I am referring to and an inline comment of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: One thing to remember is that all Firestore write operations are asynchronous.  You could return the document ID from this function, but then the caller would have no idea when that document write is actually finished.  I think it would be better if the caller received a promise that resolves with the id of the document created, so they can both know the id and when it's available.